# Конвертирование Color в ConsoleColor

Tags: c#, bitmap

Здравствуйте, пишу программу которая получает фотографию, и рисует ее на консоли, но поскольку приложение консольное, а как вы знаете что нельзя использовать `Bitmap` в консоли пришлось создать формочку. Все работает но когда дело доходит до вывода на консоль, то я получаю цвет пикселя в формате `Color`, а для изменения цвета консоли нужна `ConsoleColor`. **Прошу помочь переконвертировать `Color` в `ConsoleColor`**, спасибо!

Comment: Этот вопрос[уже был задан](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988833/converting-color-to-consolecolor) на английской версии сайта

Comment: @devended, ассоциировать вопросы между сайтами надо [по-другому](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/178988): написать `ассоциация:` поставить пробел и ссылку на вопрос (просто ссылку, не уверен, годятся ли ссылки с описанием `[]()`).

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988833/converting-color-to-consolecolor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного погуглив я наткнулся на вот этот код:

```
Color BEGIN_COLOR = Color.Red; 
ConsoleColor END_COLOR = ClosestConsoleColor(BEGIN_COLOR.R, BEGIN_COLOR.G, BEGIN_COLOR.B); 

public static ConsoleColor ConvertColor(byte r, byte g, byte b) 
{ 
    ConsoleColor ret = 0; 
    double rr = r, gg = g, bb = b, delta = double.MaxValue; 

    foreach (ConsoleColor cc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor))) 
    { 
        var n = Enum.GetName(typeof(ConsoleColor), cc); 
        var c = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(n == "DarkYellow" ? "Orange" : n);
        var t = Math.Pow(c.R - rr, 2.0) + Math.Pow(c.G - gg, 2.0) + Math.Pow(c.B - bb, 2.0); 
        if (t == 0.0) 
            return cc; 
        if (t < delta) 
        { 
            delta = t; 
            ret = cc; 
        } 
    } 
    return ret; 
}
```

Comment: Интересная идея.

Comment: Забавно. Верно понял, что оно ищет цвет, самый близкий к заданному? :)

Comment: @pavel1787mego я спрашивал про код в ответе :) Ради меня заливать не надо, я сам могу аналогичное наклепать при надобности, спасибо :)